# Unknown joined column if there is a subquery

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: `queries` and `days`, created as such:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `days` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `day` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=32 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `queries` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `from_lat` decimal(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `from_lon` decimal(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `to_lat` decimal(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `to_lon` decimal(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `duration` float NOT NULL COMMENT 'query execution duration',
  `query_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `execution_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `result` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `from_lat` (`from_lat`),
  KEY `from_lon` (`from_lon`),
  KEY `to_lat` (`to_lat`),
  KEY `to_lon` (`to_lon`),
  KEY `execution_datetime` (`execution_datetime`),
  KEY `city` (`city`),
  KEY `result` (`result`),
  KEY `execution_datetime_2` (`execution_datetime`,`city`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=27338 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Here's the contents of `days`:

```
+----+------------+
| id | day        |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 2014-12-21 |
|  2 | 2014-12-22 |
|  3 | 2014-12-23 |
|  4 | 2014-12-24 |
|  5 | 2014-12-25 |
|  6 | 2014-12-26 |
|  7 | 2014-12-27 |
|  8 | 2014-12-28 |
|  9 | 2014-12-29 |
| 10 | 2014-12-30 |
| 11 | 2014-12-31 |
| 12 | 2015-01-01 |
| 13 | 2015-01-02 |
| 14 | 2015-01-03 |
| 15 | 2015-01-04 |
| 16 | 2015-01-05 |
| 17 | 2015-01-06 |
| 18 | 2015-01-07 |
| 19 | 2015-01-08 |
| 20 | 2015-01-09 |
| 21 | 2015-01-10 |
| 22 | 2015-01-11 |
| 23 | 2015-01-12 |
| 24 | 2015-01-13 |
| 25 | 2015-01-14 |
| 26 | 2015-01-15 |
| 27 | 2015-01-16 |
| 28 | 2015-01-17 |
| 29 | 2015-01-18 |
| 30 | 2015-01-19 |
+----+------------+
```

Now if I select data from the `queries` table joined to the `days` table, that's what I have (truncated to 10 rows)

```
mysql> select d.day, q.id
    -> from days d
    -> left join queries q on date(q.execution_datetime) = d.day
    -> limit 10;
+------------+-------+
| day        | id    |
+------------+-------+
| 2014-12-21 | 15343 |
| 2014-12-21 | 15344 |
| 2014-12-21 | 15345 |
| 2014-12-21 | 15346 |
| 2014-12-21 | 15347 |
| 2014-12-21 | 15348 |
| 2014-12-21 | 15349 |
| 2014-12-21 | 15350 |
| 2014-12-21 | 15351 |
| 2014-12-21 | 15352 |
+------------+-------+
10 rows in set (0.06 sec)
```

Now if I join a simple subquery:

```
select city from queries group by city
```

then there is an error:

```
mysql> select d.day, q.id
    -> from days d,
    -> (select city from queries group by city) c
    -> left join queries q on date(q.execution_datetime) = d.day
    -> limit 10;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'd.day' in 'on clause'
```

If I join this subquery, it works:

```
mysql> select d.day, c.city
    -> from days d
    -> left join (select city from queries group by city) c on 1
    -> left join queries q on date(q.execution_datetime) = d.day and q.city = c.city
    -> limit 10;
+------------+----------+
| day        | city     |
+------------+----------+
| 2014-12-21 | adelaide |
| 2014-12-21 | adelaide |
| 2014-12-21 | adelaide |
| 2014-12-21 | adelaide |
| 2014-12-21 | adelaide |
| 2014-12-21 | adelaide |
| 2014-12-21 | adelaide |
| 2014-12-21 | adelaide |
| 2014-12-21 | adelaide |
| 2014-12-21 | adelaide |
+------------+----------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why is that?

Comment: "Now if I join a simple subquery:" - What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: filter `queries.city` with that, it's not mentioned in the tests here for the sake of brevity

Comment: Could you please add the expected output?

Comment: I have added another query that shows more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you mix comma syntax with explicit join syntax. The query cannot determine where the alias `d` comes from, because it is before a comma whereas the `on` clause is after a `join` clause.

On the other hand, when you use explicit join syntax as in your last sample, the alias `d` can be correctly determined as belonging to table `days` from one the join statements.

The [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) has this to say:

> However, the precedence of the comma operator is less than of INNER JOIN, CROSS JOIN, LEFT JOIN, and so on. If you mix comma joins with the other join types when there is a join condition, an error of the form Unknown column 'col_name' in 'on clause' may occur.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't see why mysql can't determine where `d` comes from? It's a rather simple query. Is there any doc on this? (thanks for your edit on your answer; here's an edit to my comment :p)